# Why is bitshifting useful?

Tags: bit-shift

I understand how bit-shifting works and that compilers use them to optimize runtime, but I don't understand the mathematical significance of bitshifts. What does it do to the number in decimal notation for example? How could I use bit-shifts in algorithmic programming?

Answer (score 0):

One useful application of bitshifting is [Arithmetic Shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift), in which you use bit-shifting to perform certain multiplication or division operations more efficiently than if done the traditional way.

> Shifting left by n bits on a signed or unsigned binary number has the effect of multiplying it by 2^n. Shifting right by n bits on a two's complement signed binary number has the effect of dividing it by 2^n, but it always rounds down (towards negative infinity).

As an example, take the following python code.

```
base = 5
traditional = 5 * 8  # or 5 * 2**3
shifted = 5 << 3
assert shifted == traditional
```

In this example you can see that they both yield the same result, just arriving at it in 2 different ways. This is what your compiler will do under-the-hood to optimize mathematic operations when it knows at compile time that the multiplicant is a power of 2

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I also just realized that it can be useful in generating hashes for solving problems like 0/1 knapsack or finding all possible n sized combinations of elements in an array.

Comment: @Dragoon, yes! and speaking of hashes, bitshifting and other bitwise operations (specifically XOR) are widely used in cryptography, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher for a simple example